# Most efficient way to remove list elements from column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a large DataFrame `df` with 40k+ rows:

```
                   words
0  coffee in the morning
1  good morning
2  hello my name is
3  hello world
...
```

I have a list of English stopwords that I want to remove from the column, which I do as follows:

```
df["noStopwords"] = df["words"].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i not in stopwords])

      noStopwords
0  coffee morning
1  good morning
2  hello name
3  hello world
...
```

This works but takes too long. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

EDIT:

```
print(stopwords)

['a', "a's", 'able', 'about', 'above', 'according', 'accordingly', 'across', ...]
```

Comment: Try simply making `stopwords` a `set()` – that might make things fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's any faster, but you could try [**`str.replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html). Since `words` is actually a list, we also have to `join` and `split` as well.

```py
import re
pattern = rf"\b(?:{'|'.join(map(re.escape, stopwords))})\b"
df['noStopwords'] = (df.words
    .str.join(' ')
    .str.replace(pattern, '', regex=True)
    .str.split('\s+')
)
```

Comment: I tried this but I got an error `re.error: nothing to repeat at position 3600`

Comment: Maybe it's related to your `stopwords` list. Can you edit your post and paste the output of `print(stopwords)`

Comment: I have added the `stopwords` list

Comment: Thank you. I tried your edited code, but it outputs everything as `NaN`